# Label Y-Axis stops in Highcharts solid gauges

Tags: highcharts

I have a solid gauge that looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fb5Ltxbt/

These are the requirements I've achieved thus far:

- Gauge range of 0 to 50
- If value < 40, show in red, else in green
- Display major ticks

This is what I want to add if it's possible:

- Something to indicate Y-Axis stops as defined in the code

In other words, what I want is to ADD something like the "250" indicator from the following image:

[image]

It doesn't have to be an additional number, just something, anything, that marks each stop.

JSFiddle source code below:

```js
var gaugeOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    backgroundColor: null
  },
  title: null,
  pane: {
    center: ['35%', '75%'],
    size: '100%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      innerRadius: '60%',
      outerRadius: '100%',
      shape: 'arc'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  // the value axis
  yAxis: {
    // Add something to indicate each of these stops
    stops: [
      [0.8, 'red'],
      [1.0, 'green']
    ],
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickInterval: 10, // Keep the labels for these ticks
    minorTickInterval: 2.5,
    title: null,
    labels: {
      y: -5,
      style: {
        'color': 'black',
        'fontWeight': 'bold'
      }
    }
  }
};

var chart = Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    title: null
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'ABC',
    data: [30],
    dataLabels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.y;
      },
      y: -20,
      style: {
        textShadow: false,
        'color': 'black',
        'fontSize': '2em'
      },
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' km/h'
    }
  }]
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 1024px; height: 768px; margin: 0;">
  <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</div>
```

I have seen [how to make specific labels outside gauge chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515493/how-to-make-specific-labels-outside-gauge-chart) but it requires all normal ticks to be removed. I'd don't want them to be removed if possible but please say so if what I want is not possible too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can an additional yAxis to achieve additional ticks. The additional axis should be [linked](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo) to the main axis. Then, it has the same scale as the main axis and you gain control over additional, independent ticks - you define specific ticks via [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions).

```
{
  linkedTo: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  minorTickLength: 0,
  tickPositions: [35],
  tickLength: 75,
  labels: {
    x: 30,
    y: -30,
    style: {
      fontSize: '25px'
    }
  }
}]
```

#### Live example and output

https://jsfiddle.net/ym2tvzy7/

[image: gauge, two y axes]

If you want ticks with different color and styles, you can add more axes.

https://jsfiddle.net/ym2tvzy7/1/

[image: gauge, more axes]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirements correctly
May be this will help not exactly as your requirement anyway as an alternative

You can also try :-

```
plotBands: [{
      from: 39.5,
      to: 40.5,
      color: '#55BF3B' // green
}]
```

```js
var gaugeOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    backgroundColor: null
  },
  title: null,
  pane: {
    center: ['35%', '75%'],
    size: '100%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      innerRadius: '60%',
      outerRadius: '100%',
      shape: 'arc'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  // the value axis
  yAxis: {
    stops: [
      [0.8, 'red'],
      [1.0, 'green']
    ],
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickInterval: 10,
    minorTickInterval: 2.5,
    title: null,
    labels: {
      y: -5,
      style: {
        'color': 'black',
        'fontWeight': 'bold'
      }
    }
  }
};

var chart = Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    title: null,
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 40,
      color: '#55BF3B' // green
    }]
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'ABC',
    data: [31],
    dataLabels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.y;
      },
      y: -20,
      style: {
        textShadow: false,
        'color': 'black',
        'fontSize': '2em'
      },
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' km/h'
    }
  }]
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 1024px; height: 768px; margin: 0;">
  <div id="chartContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the thing. I already have existing labels for major ticks at regular intervals of 10. I want to keep those. Then, I also want something in addition to indicate the y-axis stop at 40. Somewhat like what you've done but without removing pre-existing tick labels.

Comment: See my edit, hopefully it clarifies what I'm looking for.

Comment: updated by it is not as excat but can be an alternative

Comment: hmm not really what I'm looking for but I guess it's something. I'll think about it. Thanks!